# How to fill all dates of selected month in DataTable

Tags: c#, date

I am trying to fill all dates of a selected month in a DataTable. I have done like below mentioned method but its not working.

```
public DataTable  GetDates()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
int year = Convert.ToInt32(ddyear.SelectedItem.Value);//I selected year 2015
int month = Convert.ToInt32(ddmonth.SelectedItem.Value);//I selected  month 3
for ( date = new DateTime(year, month, 1); date.Month == month; date =    date.AddDays(1))
{
  dt.Rows.Add(date);
  date = date.AddDays(1);
}
return dt;
}
```

How can I do it??

Comment: How is it not working? Any exception?

Comment: @Cuong Le,Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.It is the exception

Comment: You have to add column (with name and datatype) to datatable first. Currently it `dt` has no column. And in `for` loop why are you incrementing date twice (one inside the block and another in the update statement part of `for`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public DataTable GetDates()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        int year = Convert.ToInt32(ddyear.SelectedItem.Value);
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(ddmonth.SelectedItem.Value);

        int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        for (int i = 0; i < daysInMonth; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Date"] = new DateTime(year, month, i + 1);
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Kindly add some more details